# OpenCV region growing

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to the find skin regions in an image. By using back projection, I can transform the image into a single channel image with each pixel value representing the probability of that pixel being skin.

I have two thresholds, T1 and T2, where T1 > T2. By thresholding the image with T1 and T2, I get two images I1 and I2, how can I find the regions in I2 such that these regions contain regions from I1?

Sorry for my bad English. Many thanks.

Comment: Could [YCrCb](http://spottrlabs.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/super-simple-skin-detector-in-opencv.html) do the trick ?

Comment: well I'm using statistical method to calculate the probability, I want to be able to update the probability rather than just checking whether the ycrcb value just fall within certain ranges